# self.view setFrame not working with iOS 8 and Nav Controller

Tags: ios, ios8

Has anyone noticed that self.view setFrame has stopped working with Nav Controller in iOS 8. It works just fine if the view controller does not have a nav controller, but otherwise, it doesnt. Does anyone know a work around? Currently I am using

```
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,-100,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
```

But this doesnt work anymore

Answer (score 16):

Try to set "setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints" to YES before setting the frame:

```
[self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
```

And then set your frame:

```
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,-100,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if setFrame has changed, but I can say that 'bounds' has changed in iOS 8 where the bounds property of the UIScreen class now reflects the device orientation, so the width and height will swop when in landscape.

iOS 8 offers a new nativeBounds property on UIScreen that doesn't change with orientation, but note that it is measured in pixels, not points.